# convert into string using python

Tags: python

How can i convert this input into a string?

```
GET /learn/tutorials/351079-weekend-project-secure-your-system-with-port-knocking?name=MyName&married=not+single&male=yes HTTP/1.1
Host: merch1.localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;en-GB; rv:1.8.0.11) Gecko/20070312 Firefox/1.5.0.11
Accept: text/xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
```

I need the output to be:

`GET /learn/tutorials/351079-weekend-project-secure-your-system-with-port-knocking?name=MyName&married=not+single&male=yes HTTP/1.1 Host: merch1.localhost User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;en-GB; rv:1.8.0.11) Gecko/20070312 Firefox/1.5.0.11 Accept: text/xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Keep-Alive: 300 Connection: keep-alive`

Comment: Where are you receiving this input?  What have you tried?

Comment: possible duplicate of [i need to convert the input from telnet to  a list in twisted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3732345/i-need-to-convert-the-input-from-telnet-to-a-list-in-twisted)

Comment: The only transformation that I see in there is removing newlines from the headers.  Is that what you are trying to accomplish?  Also, I notice an `HTTP/1.1` in the output that is not anywhere in the input....

Comment: @Phoenix: I see the `HTTP/1.1` at the end of the first line; looks to me like he's simply _replacing_ each newline with a space character, i.e. `s.replace('\r\n', ' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

Just split the input into lines and join them:

```
ins = """\
GET /learn/tutorials/351079-weekend-project-secure-your-system-with-port-knocking?name=MyName&married=not+single&male=yes HTTP/1.1
Host: merch1.localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;en-GB; rv:1.8.0.11) Gecko/20070312 Firefox/1.5.0.11
Accept: text/xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 300
Connection: keep-alive
"""

outs = 'GET /learn/tutorials/351079-weekend-project-secure-your-system-with-port-knocking?name=MyName&married=not+single&male=yes HTTP/1.1 Host: merch1.localhost User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows;en-GB; rv:1.8.0.11) Gecko/20070312 Firefox/1.5.0.11 Accept: text/xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5 Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5 Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7 Keep-Alive: 300 Connection: keep-alive'

assert( ' '.join(ins.splitlines()) == outs)
```